# How the input shape of noise vector affects the Generator in GANs?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I can't find an explanation about how the shape of noise vector (Z) affects the Discriminator in the Generative Adversarial Networks. All the tutorials use shape (100,) but why? Let's suppose that the shape of the images is 128x128. I understand  that GAN tries to learn the function that transforms the noise distribution to the real one, but how the size of it affects the Discriminator? It's better to use bigger input shape or smaller?

Comment: Did you make experiments with a small and bigger noise input ? I mean, regarding classification accuracy ?

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres thanks you for replay. I'm looking for some theoretical explanation or if there're not, I accept that it's just empirical best. But is it good for every problem? Idk, this is why I'm asking if there are some explanation

Comment: I think you provide a bigger noise input, the details of output will be different. Think about a Variational Autoencoder: when you reduce dimensionality, you blur the output image.

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. Do you think there are some relationship between that noise vector and image shape? What you actually mean is that you need +- same size to don't lose image information? That makes sense.

Comment: No, not image shape, but the definition of fake generated images, maybe this can fool the discriminator easily.